# Elmah filtering based on APPL_MD_PATH Options

Tags: asp.net, elmah

I posted this to the ELMAH newsgroup, but haven't received a reply in 5 days, so I figured I'd try here.

Here are 2 test statements that I think do the same thing, but neither 
seem to work:

```
      <test> 
          <equal binding="Context.Request.ServerVariables 
['APPL_MD_PATH']" value="/LM/W3SVC/1/Root/Ameren/CCI" type="String"/> 
      </test> 
      <test> 
        <jscript> 
          <expression> 
            <![CDATA[ 
            // @assembly mscorlib 
            // @assembly System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a 
            // @import System.IO 
            // @import System.Web 
            Context.Request.ServerVariables['APPL_MD_PATH'] == '/ 
LM/W3SVC/1/Root/Ameren/CCI' 
            ]]> 
          </expression> 
        </jscript> 
      </test>
```

I'm pretty new to Elmah filtering, so any help as to why this is not 
working would be immensely helpful.